# How to register archive file name as variable in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

FYI: This is Ansible 2.7

I'm archiving a directory, and I need to grab the file name I create and register it as a variable for further use in the playbook.

```
- name: Compress directory /etc/apache2/ into /tmp
  archive:
    path: /etc/apache2
    dest: /tmp/{{ ansible_hostname }}-apache2-{{ ansible_date_time.date }}.tar.gz
  register: archive_name
```

This gives me a file `/tmp/hostname-apache2-09-01-2022.tar.gz`, but I do not know how to register that as a variable. Is this possible?

I specifically need just the file name, not the full path.

I tried:

```
- debug:
    var: archive_name.arcroot
```

However, all it gives me back is:

```
ok: [hostname] => {
    "archive_name.arcroot": "/etc/"
}
```

I also don't see anything else as an option [in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/archive_module.html#return-values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first save the desired path or just the filename into a variable and then use it in all your required tasks.

```yaml
- name: Define archive_name
  set_fact:
    my_archive_name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}-apache2-{{ ansible_date_time.date }}.tar.gz"

- name: Compress directory /etc/apache2/ into /tmp
  archive:
    path: /etc/apache2
    dest: "/tmp/{{ my_archive_name }}"
```

Note that Jinja expressions should always be enclosed in quotes.

---

You can also store the whole path in the variable, including the `/tmp/` prefix.

If you need only the filename elsewhere, you can extract it with the [`basename` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names).

Example: `{{ "/tmp/hostname-apache2-09-01-2022.tar.gz" | basename }}`
Returns: `hostname-apache2-09-01-2022.tar.gz`